# Reading from a data file

Tags: python

I am trying to read from a txt file I am including with my pyqt application.

The problem I am having is that the `os.path.dirname(__file__)` is returning the directory where the module that houses finding the data file exists not the directory where main() lives. In this case a subdirectory of the application directory not the application directory.

Is there a way to always return the directory where `main()` is being called from ?

That or can I get the directory to this text file in main() and pass it to Mainform() somehow ?

The reason for all this is because I want to put the .txt in the same directory as main.py so when I deploy my frozen application the text file can be found. (on OSX and WIN)

Thanks

Comment: look at `os.getcwd()` rather than `os.path.dirname(__file__)`

Comment: that is actually returning the directory above my project directory.

Comment: nevermind I figured out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A setup like this may work for you:

**main.py**

```
import other

def main():
    print other.get_data_files_dir()

main()
```

**other.py**

```
import os
import sys

def get_data_files_dir():
    namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # caller's globals
    return os.path.dirname(namespace['__file__'])
```